# How do I add a css class to particular rows in slickGrid?

Tags: slickgrid

I've searched everywhere to find out how to add a class to a particular row in slickgrid.  It looks like there used to be a rowCssClasses property but it's gone now.  Any help on this would be extremely appreciated.

**Update**: I figured it out using the getItemMetadata...so before you render, you have to do something like this:

```
dataView.getItemMetadata = function (row) {
    if (this.getItem(row).compareThis > 1) {
        return {
            'cssClasses': 'row-class'
        };
    }
};
```

That will inject that 'row-class' into the row that matches the if statement.  It seems that this getItemMetadata function doesn't exist until you put it there and slickGrid checks to see if there's anything in there.  It makes it kind of difficult to figure out it's options but if you search for getItemMetadata in the slick.grid.js file you should find some hidden treasures! I hope this helps someone!

If there's a better way of doing this, please let me know.

Answer (score 12):

In newer versions of SlickGrid, DataView brings its own getItemMetadata to provide formatting for group headers and totals. It is easy to chain that with your own implementation though. For example,

```js
function row_metadata(old_metadata_provider) {
  return function(row) {
    var item = this.getItem(row),
        ret = old_metadata_provider(row);

    if (item && item._dirty) {
      ret = ret || {};
      ret.cssClasses = (ret.cssClasses || '') + ' dirty';
    }

    return ret;
  };
}

dataView.getItemMetadata = row_metadata(dataView.getItemMetadata);
```

Comment: what's value for `row` parameter? I debug and see `row` always `=0`, so `item` always is first item in datasource.

Comment: Since upgrading from slickgrid v2 to v5 I found I needed to use `ret = old_metadata_provider.call(this,row)` instead.

Answer (score 7):

```
        myDataView.getItemMetadata = function(index)
        {
            var item = myDataView.getItem(index);
            if(item.isParent === true) {
                return { cssClasses: 'parentRow' };
            }
            else {
                return { cssClasses: 'childRow' };
            }
        };
```

//In my CSS

```
       .parentRow {
           background-color:  #eeeeee;
        }
        .childRow {
           background-color:  #ffffff;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the setCellCssStyles function:
https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Slick.Grid#wiki-setCellCssStyles

> grid.setCellCssStyles(key, hash)
>
> key - A string key. Will overwrite any data already associated with
>   this key.
>
> hash - A hash of additional cell CSS classes keyed by row number and
>   then by column id. Multiple CSS classes can be specified and separated
>   by space.
>
> Example:
>
> {
>       0:    {
>           "number_column":    "cell-bold",
>           "title_column":     "cell-title cell-highlighted"
>       },
>       4:    {
>           "percent_column":    "cell-highlighted"
>       } }

I used that to highlight edited fields in my grid. I didn't like the getItemMetadata method.

Comment: This answer seemed to be a lot simpler and also had the advantage of allowing me to focus on the cells rather than the row. I used it to change the background of every cell in the row to make it appear that the entire row was highlighted. This helped because I wanted to overwrite cell specific background colors applied earlier, so I needed to select the cells individually, not the row object.