# SlickGrid - Handling DataView with grid.onAddNewRow

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony, twig, slickgrid

I am using SlickGrid to generate a data grid. The data is fetched by a jQuery AJAX call. With the advice from https://stackoverflow.com/a/11611477/2294855 I am able to handle the response data and set it to the DataView. But my problem arises when I make the Grid option "enableAddRow: true".

Here, when I try to add something in the new row, whenever I insert something in any cell and shift to other, the data is not there. For example:

My declaration for the grid:

```js
var categories, categoryList, subjectList, data, grid;
var url = "{{ url('get_data', {'_prefix': app.request.get('_prefix')}) }}";

var dataView = new Slick.Data.DataView();

var columns = [
    {id: "serial", name: "Ordnungsnummer", field: "serial", editor: Slick.Editors.Integer, validator: requiredFieldValidator, sortable: true},
    {id: "category", name: "Kategorie", field: "category", editor: Slick.Editors.categoryDropdown, formatter: Slick.Formatters.category, validator: requiredFieldValidator, sortable: true},
    {id: "subject", name: "Themenbereich", field: "subject", editor: Slick.Editors.subjectDropdown, formatter: Slick.Formatters.subject, validator: requiredFieldValidator, sortable: true},
    {id: "week", name: "Schulwoche", field: "week", editor: Slick.Editors.Integer, validator: requiredFieldValidator, sortable: true},
    {id: "note", name: "Anmerkung", field: "note", editor: Slick.Editors.LongText, validator: requiredFieldValidator}
];

var options = {
    editable: true,
    enableAddRow: true,
    enableCellNavigation: true,
    asyncEditorLoading: true,
    forceFitColumns: true,
    topPanelHeight: 25
};

grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", dataView, columns, options);

// wire up model events to drive the grid
dataView.onRowCountChanged.subscribe(function (e, args) {
    grid.updateRowCount();
    grid.render();
});

dataView.onRowsChanged.subscribe(function (e, args) {
    grid.invalidateRows(args.rows);
    grid.render();
});

grid.onAddNewRow.subscribe(function (e, args) {
    var item = args.item;
    var column = args.column;
    grid.invalidateRow(dataView.length);
    dataView.push(item);
    grid.updateRowCount();
    grid.render();
});

function fetchData() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        data: {schoolclass: {{ schoolclass }}},
        success: function( response ) {
            createGrid(response);
        }
    });
}

function requiredFieldValidator(value) {
    if (value == null || value == undefined || !value.length) {
        return {valid: false, msg: "This is a required field"};
    }
    else {
        return {valid: true, msg: null};
    }
}

function createGrid(response) {

    data = response.data;

    categories = response.categories;
    categoryList = generateCategoryList(categories);
    subjectList = generateSubjectList(categories);



    dataView.beginUpdate();
    dataView.setItems(data);
    console.log(data);
    dataView.endUpdate();
}

function generateCategoryList(categories) {
    var categoryList = {};

    $.each(categories, function(index, item) {
        categoryList[item.id] = item.name;
    });

    return categoryList;
}

function generateSubjectList(categories) {
    var subjectList = {};

    $.each(categories, function(index, category) {
        $.each(category.subjects, function(index, subjects) {
            subjectList[subjects.id] = subjects.name;
        });
    });

    return subjectList;
}

function sendData(data) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        data: data,
        success: function( response ) {
            createGrid(response);
            alert("data successfully saved");
        },
        error: function(textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("sorry could not save the data");
            console.log("text Status = "+ textStatus);
            console.log("Error Thrown = "+ errorThrown);
        }
    });
}

$(function () {

    fetchData();

    $("#save").click(function() {

        var newData = JSON.stringify(grid.getData());

        sendData(newData);
    });
})
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To address the issue at hand, the reason your data isn't present is because of `dataView.push(item);` in the `onAddNewRow` handler.
Use the [addItem](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/master/slick.dataview.js#L345) function of the dataview.

I assume your data has an `id` property on each item, otherwise the data wouldn't be displaying. Thus, you'll also need to address the issue of the new data element needing a unique `id` by adding it to the `var item = args.item;` in the handler.

If your data elements have an existing field, take `serial` for example, that is unique across all the elements, then you can configure your dataview to use that field as the required id by passing it into the [setItems](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/master/slick.dataview.js#L126) function. At that point, you wouldn't have to manually assign the `id`.

Additionally, you'll have an issue saving the data because of `grid.getData()`. To get the data from within the dataview use `grid.getData().getItems()`.