# how to change row color on scrollRow

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I have slick grid that I want to change row background color, when I  find search result:

```
    protected showMatchItem() {
        this.searchresult.text(`${this.currentMatchIndex + 1} از ${this.matchIndexes.length}`);
        this.slickGrid.scrollRowIntoView(this.matchIndexes[this.currentMatchIndex], true);
       
        this.slickGrid.setCellCssStyles("highlight", this.matchIndexes[this.currentMatchIndex]) ;

    }
```

.highlight {
background: yellow
}

Comment: mostly a duplicate of this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8930167/how-do-i-add-a-css-class-to-particular-rows-in-slickgrid)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add a css class to particular rows in slickGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8930167/how-do-i-add-a-css-class-to-particular-rows-in-slickgrid)

Comment: Thanks but No ,I want , search for Example "Apple" when find this world change row style.